# How to check if all divs are hidden with variable class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to javascript/jQuery so apologies if this is a very basic question.

I have a variable which uses Math.random to select one of 9 potential classes from an array, the classes are the same except with a different number 1-9 at the end. I want to use javascript to check if all elements with this class are hidden. I can get it to check if all divs are hidden when I actually specify the class, but am not sure how to do this with a variable or expression. Below is what I'm using at the moment, which only works when the div is specified.

```
if ($('div.item9:visible').length == 0)
```

I assumed something like this would do what I want, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 if ($(variable + ':visible').length == 0)
```

EDIT: if ($(variable + ':visible').length == 0) this does work, I had another div on the page with this class which I didn't realise and therefore there was always an unhidden element, thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Why don't you use the same class for all of them? They all seem to be a group. Maybe under a parent `id`...

Comment: The different classes give a different colour to the elements via css so I want to be able to pick at random and check when they're hidden.

Comment: @thill your code should work fine, assuming "variable" has the appropriate stuff in it.

Comment: Can't you add another common class for all of them? Things are usually easier :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same variable in your class name which you have used to select a number from 1-9 for example

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1);
```

this will generate a random integer between 1-10 then you can just add the x in the class name
like this

```
if ($('div.item'+x+':visible').length == 0)
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var elements = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function getRandomClassNumber(){

    //will give you random index
    var index = Math.floor((Math.random()*elements.length));
    return (elements[index]);
}

$("#btnRandom").on("click",function(){

var classNumber =  getRandomClassNumber();      
    if($(".item"+classNumber).is(":visible")){
      alert("item" + classNumber + " is visible");
    }else{
      alert("item" + classNumber + " not visible");      
    }
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6neFA/